# CRest / How to configure to accecpt only JSON responce

Tags: java, android, rest

I am using CRest to deserialize a JSON stream on Android. My first steps looks very promising.

To get the JSON stream from the server and not the XML one I use the following construct:
(`Accept: application/json`)

```
@EndPoint("http://localhost:8080/myserver/rest")
@Param(name = "Accept", value = "application/json", dest = Destination.HEADER)
    public interface VersionService {

    @ConnectionTimeout(10000)
    @Path("/version")
    VersionTO getVersion();

}
```

This works but it's a bit annoying to copy the "Param thing" for every service. 
Is there a better way to configure all Services at one place only to return JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'm afraid there isn't any simple way in the current version, but feel free to open a request on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/codegist/crest/issues).

Cheers,

Laurent

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar situation where I used a custom HTTP client. In your case it could look like as follows:

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
client.addRequestInterceptor(new HttpRequestInterceptor() {
    public void process(HttpRequest request, HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException {
        request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    }
});

CRestBuilder builder = new CRestBuilder();
builder.expectsJson();
builder.setRestService(new HttpClientRestService(client));
```

Another option is to set default parameter for ClientPNames.DEFAULT_HEADERS of the custom HttpClient instance.
Details can be found on http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/httpagent.html.